# What materials would / could be immune to magic?

Tags: magic, ancient-history, balancing-magic-systems

For my story/novel I'm looking for materials that would/could be immune to magic.

**Context:**
One of the characters accidentally drank a transformation potion that turned her into a newt.

So, as I can't have people walking around naked after they changed back to human forms, I'm trying to figure out a way that makes her dress (made from linen) and sandals (made from leather) change with her. While other things, like certain pieces of jewellery, don't change into the newt-form with her.

**Note:** The time setting of the story is quite wide as it is a "mix" of Ancient Greece (2000 Bc> ) and Ancient Rome but leans more towards Ancient Greece. 
So preferably, the materials would need to have been available during that time range, preferably during the Ancient Greek time period.

**Edit**
My sincere apologies for not being elaborate enough, and I'm sorry I didn't mention a few things in my original post. Some further explanation:
Although I'm using magic, I would like to keep my story as close to reality as possible. For example: Magic could be similar to electricity, as in having the same properties: the way it flows, conducts and such.

**Edit 2**
Again sorry, apparently I'm bad at this... so, let's try again:
What I'm trying to ask is:
I'm looking for ideas on how to implement the magic and it's rules in order to keep it as realistic as possible. So what from the real world could I base my magic system on or what could the magic be similar to e.g. electricity, sound waves, etc.

Comment: If you control the magic system (and you do, as an author), then you define how it works. I'm not sure why you ask us to devise that for you. If you say that clothes that were dyed red on a Tuesday are not affected by magic then...so be it. As long as it's consistent, it's fine. And transformation that preserves clothing is *so common* that it's pretty much the expectation. If you've shapeshifting that somehow loses clothes that's going to impress people more than "oh, right, they have clothes".

Comment: The properties of magic are unique to your world, and magic behaves exactly as you decide to. Any material could be magic resistant if you deem it so. This is because magic is entirely fictional so you could assign literally any property to it you want.

Comment: You've already handwaved in the idea that your magic conforms to cultural norms of nudity and notions of clothing, so you may as well handwave it what it can and cannot transform, as well. The rules are all yours; we can't second guess you here, and there isn't really any notion of what would be a correct answer or not so the question isn't a great fit for this site.

Comment: I don't quite see how "materials would/could be immune to magic" is related to this!? Could you be so kind and explain it more thoroughly!? Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi welcome, I challenge you to find the worldbuilding tour site! Just kidding I only have my mobile right now so can't add links anyway it would be better if you ask about the clothes instead.

Comment: @user6760 I'm sorry if I misunderstood the purpose of the website. I just checked the tour you suggested and I sincerely can't find what I did wrong. My sincere apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: Hahaha you did good, that page is supposed to help you get started on your journey into pro worldbuilding. Have fun ;D

Comment: Could be or is similar to electricity? You are asking advice on rules to defend against it but offer little on how it works offensively, perhaps rethink your magic system and when you got it a bit more clear for yourself ask again. But besides electricity you could also look at other properties then conducting like vibration, temperature, sound dampening and so on.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and the many edits. I'm new to this website, or similar websites for that matter. Maybe, the fact that I'm Dutch and English isn't my native language could be a factor to why I have a hard time explaining what I'm really asking? 
Please bear with me and I will do my best to become a functional and understood member of this online society. And please, if I'm doing something wrong, correct me. With feedback, not just critique and help me to improve. Thank you all for the comments so far!

Comment: You've hit a trope, females always appear naked, males at least keep their trousers or remain fully dressed. You can use it, abuse it, or ignore it, they've all been done over the years.

Comment: Sorry if anyone has already mentioned this, but 2000 BC is kind of a while back. You're referring to a time period when the Sumerians weren't ancient history yet. Hammurabi was in power in the 2nd millenium BC. Mycenaean Greece starts in 1600 BC, for reference. Can you please 'worldbuild' what you'd like to see so we have a more accurate idea of the time period and what we're looking for?

Comment: @cyber101 Thank you for your response. No one has mentioned that before. But I kind of took a weird guess there with the 2000 bc. I find it hard to pinpoint a specific date in Ancient Greek history so I did a really quick research just so I could at least name a period.
Don't get me wrong, I'm not writing without doing research, I love doing research and do a lot of it for my story. The reason I didn't do extensive research for the actual specific time period is because my story only needs a "loose" estimate to paint the picture and have something to hold on to. 1

Comment: @cyber101 Though, I did found that around 2000 bce, the early Greeks settled in the Peloponnese. And in  2000 - 1450 bce, Minoan civilization started in Crete and the Aegean. So that's how I got the 2000 bce. 
Thanks for giving me the heads up though! You definitely inspired me to do more research on that matter! Maybe this isn't the right place to ask, but do you have some suggestions to where to start?

Comment: Yeah this place isn't meant for chatting. If anyone else is reading this, how do people communicate on this website without moving the entire thing to chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you suggest that magic is like electricity I suggest to use Antistatic garments.
They are made of strong fibers coated with rubber or plastic.

In your case I think you can replace rubber and plastic (not available in ancient Greek) with natural resin.

Another thing you can use is a wearable Faraday cage, not very comfortable, but very effective.

In any case your is magic not electricity, so you don't really need something effective against electricity, take some ideas and adapt to ancient Greek.

For example instead of a full Farady cage, a coat of mail could be effective against magic.